# Can anyone give me a suggestion of a good monk to learn Buddhism?

Tags: buddha

Can someone give a name of a monk to learn Buddhism?

Thanks

Comment: How about "the Buddha"? But seriously perhaps this question could be more specific. What do you want to learn? What do you know already? Do you want to learn in person, or via a book, or pre-recorded video, or online chat? Does it matter which 'school' or branch of Buddhism, which country, which language?

Comment: I am really not at a level where I can understood the Suttas by my self therefor I need help to understand it from a monk that knows the sutras.

Answer (score 3):

For the doctrinal/technical side of the Teaching, you can't go wrong with Bhikkhu Bodhi. He actually live streams his courses from Chuang Yen monastery every Saturday morning US Eastern time at 10 AM. Simply go to youtube.com and type: "chuang yen". Also check out his excellent book [In the Buddha's Words](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0861714911)

Answer (score 2):

There are so many but just off the top of my head, Bhante Bodhidhamma is good for students that are a bit advanced & Bhante Yuttadhammo has a Youtube channel that I think works quite well. You might not think that a monk with a Youtube channel would work but he makes it work for beginners.

Teacher monastics no longer with us:

Ayya Khema,  Ajahn Chah,  Pema Chodron,  Mahasi Sayadaw and   Dogen are all examples of very skilled teachers each with their own unique yet appropriately conforming approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Bhikkhu Buddhadasa. Consider staring with:

1. [Two Kinds of Language](https://www.dhammatalks.net/Books5/Bhikkhu_Buddhadasa_Two_Kinds_of_Language.htm)
2. [Buddha Dhamma for University Students](https://www.dhammatalks.net/Books5/Buddhadassa_Bhikkhu_Buddha_Dhamma_for_University_Students.pdf)
3. [Nirvana For Everyone](https://www.dhammatalks.net/Articles/Bhikkhu_Buddhadasa_NIBBANA_FOR_EVERYONE.htm)
4. [Natural Cure for Spiritual Disease](https://www.dhammatalks.net/Books/Bhikkhu_Buddhadasa_Natural_Cure_for_Spiritual_Disease1.htm)
5. [Anapanasati: Mindfulness with Breathing - Unveiling the Secrets of Life](https://www.dhammatalks.net/Books3/Bhikkhu_Buddhadasa_Anapanasati_Mindfulness_with_Breathing.htm)
6. [Anatta & Rebirth](https://www.dhammatalks.net/Books7/Buddhadasa_Bhikkhu_Anatta_and_Rebirth.pdf)
7. [Kamma in Buddhism](https://www.suanmokkh.org/system/books/files/000/000/089/original/Kamma_in_buddhism_Buddhadasa_bhikkhu.pdf?1485253529)

Comment: Hey DD, are you familiar with Ajahn Anan Akincano? Might check him out & let me know what you think of him.

Comment: Buddhadasa is for learning about Buddhist theory from.  Ajahn Anan Akincano i don't know about but many monks become the "flavour of the month". Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

For samatha;
Ajahn Brahm, Ajahn Sujato, Ajahn Kalyano, Ajahn Anan (EN)

In general the TFT seems to have a strong samatha training.

For mindfulness, ardency, alertness & discipline;
Ven. Yuttadhamma

For wisdom;
Imho you need to do your own analysis but you can entertain the ideas of the manyfold various teachers until you make up your mind in regards to the points of controversy.

For the more doctrinally accurate translations;
Ajahn Thanissaro

Foremost pleasant translations;
Bhikkhu Bodhi

There are many other monks who all have their own relative good qualities but these stand out as specialists in those particular fields as far as i can tell.